# How do you find the speed of sound in the problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acoustics

A stone is dropped into a 40m deep well. The sound of the splash is heard 2.95 seconds after the stone is dropped. Find the speed of sound.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please be sure to read: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let, $t$=time taken by the stone;
$T$=Time taken by the sound(both are in second)
$d$=depth of the well and $s$=velocity of the sound

Use the following equations:

$d=1/2 gt^2$ (For stone)

$d=sT$ (For sound)

$t+T=2.95$

Finally, put $d=40 m$, solve for $t$. Find out $T$ and hence $s$ i.e the speed of sound.

Comment: I don't see how the second equation $d = \frac{1}{2}gt^2$ is valid for sound. The second equation is for the stone which you have already mentioned before. There should be just 3 equations.